# Does the "refresh_token" refresh "access_token" with "client_secrets.json" in the background?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

Finally, i made it work the Youtube Data API V3.0 with the new NuGet. Thank you very much. I have one more question about "access_token".

We can use "access_token" only for an hour. Do we have to refresh this "access_token" every hour or does the "refresh_token" make it by itself with "client_secrets.json" in the background? If i have to refresh it by myself, can you please show me the code or the document that i can use?

Thank you very much.

I do apologize if i used wrong grammar.

Comment: From my experience with oauth 2.0, you need to refresh the access_token using the refresh_token after the access_token expires. I don't know much about Youtube's data API though. If it implements oauth 2.0, you'll need a token uri and you'll need to POST your refresh_token to that uri and set the grant_type to refresh_token.

Comment: Thank you Cameron. I just got an answer from Jeff Posnick. Here's the answer "The client library is supposed to take care of automatically refreshing the OAuth 2 token. If you notice any problems with that, please let the maintainer of the library know via https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/support "

But the client library is not taking care of all tokens. There is something like "next_token" in Playlist. I will ask it to the support.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on Google's Youtube Data API v3, you need to implement your own oauth client. I'm assuming that you have registered your app and have a client_id and client_secret. These are needed when making requests to Google's API.

First, you need to load `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` as that is Google's oauth2 provider. A sample request might look like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
  redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback&
  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&
  response_type=code&
  access_type=offline
```

A sample response:

```
http://localhost/oauth2callback?code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf
```

Assuming that your user accepts access from Google, you will then need to exchange the authorization code returned from Google to get the refresh and access tokens.

You will need to POST to this address:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Your post data will include the code returned from the previous response, your client_id, your client_secret, your redirect_uri, and the grant_type.

Sample post data:

```
code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&
client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&
redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZTtm7SuokEB-RGtbBty9IIlNiP9-eNMMQKtXdMP3sfjL1Fc",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/HKSmLFXzqP0leUihZp2xUt3-5wkU7Gmu2Os_eBnzw74"
}
```

Then you should store your access_token and refresh_token for later. The access_token expires in 3600 seconds (1 hour).

To refresh your access token, post something like this:

```
client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=XTHhXh1SlUNgvyWGwDk1EjXB&
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsixUH6kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

Full developer documentation is available here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

Comment: Thank you Cameron. I think they changed everything with the new update. The client library is supposed to take care of automatically refreshing the OAuth 2 token. But the client library does not take care of everything such as "next_token" in Playlist. I will ask that to the support as Jess told me. I will update this question as soon as i will get an answer from them.